# Mathematical definition of reversible processes

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, group-theory, reversibility

If I label an initial thermodynamic state as $\psi$ and the final thermodynamic state as $\xi$ then can I say that under a [reversible process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reversible_process_%28thermodynamics%29) the two states are related to each other by a continuous transformation and an irreversible process is one that is a discrete transformation. It is then noted that the generators of the continuous transformation can be given a group structure(probably non-abelian not sure) and thus it is possible to go from $\xi$ back to $\psi$ but this is not the case for irreversible processes that do not have a group structure.

Is it right to say whatever I have said above?

Comment: Your question is if we have thoughts? Stack Exchange is suited for Q&A style help, not open discussion.

Comment: I am sorry I have made the correction

Comment: Where did you get this from? Thermodynamics is an asymptotic theory of homogeneous systems (which don't exist in nature) coupled to infinite thermal reservoirs (which also don't exist in nature) and reversible processes (which don't exist in nature, either) would take infinitely long, even if they existed... which they don't. I think you should start understanding on the physical level why it makes sense, anyway, before you are trying to make up a new axiomatic description of thermodynamics.

Comment: How should then one see reversible and irreversible processes?

Comment: A reversible process is one that maintains equilibrium at all times, an irreversible one does not. In practice all processes are irreversible and reversible processes are the asymptotic best case scenario. Did you research this on the internet or in a textbook, first, before making up your own "definitions"?

Comment: Because the reversible processes are always at equilibrium in their intermediate states, I can represent them in the state space and hence we have a trajectory of the process. All that I am saying is that the evolution is continuous and hence can be described as linear transformations. Much like the time evolution of a dynamical system by the Hamiltonian. I am considering only reversible processes and not irreversible ones.

Comment: The evolution of irreversible processes is continuous, as well, it just doesn't happen on your state space manifold. You can chose ever more complicated representations for irreversible processes, there is a fully developed theory for that, too, it's just next to useless. That you are not the first one to think of making this into a differential geometry problem will be obvious when you go into the library and grab some of the more mathematical thermodynamics books. When I was studying  relativity, I noticed that the equations of GR look very similar to those of TD, and not by coincidence. :-)

Comment: I am totally surprised. Thanks for your input. Could you please give some references ? I will search online and in library but if you do remember some it would be very much helpful.